# How to use onchange function select tag for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, combobox

I am trying to update my combobox values while user changing it.

in html codes:

```
<select class="combobox" id="recs" name="recs" onchange="changeRecs">
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
    <option value=20>20</option>
</select>
```

javascript codes:

```
$scope.changeRecs = function() {
    //somethings
    $scope.loadTable();
}
```

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an error in your syntax:

```
<select class="combobox" id="recs" name="recs" onchange="changeRecs">
<!-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You forgot the parentesis `()`.

You just need to do:

```
document.querySelector("#recs").onchange = function (e) {
  // some things
  alert("Changed");
}
```

And in jQuery, you do:

```
$('#recs').on('change', function(){
    //action here
});
```

**Snippet (Vanilla JS)**

```js
document.querySelector("#recs").onchange = function (e) {
  // some things
  alert("Changed to " + this.value);
}
```

```html
<select class="combobox" id="recs" name="recs" onchange="changeRecs">
  <option value=5>5</option>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
</select>
```

**Snippet (jQuery)**

```js
$('#recs').on('change', function () {
  //action here
  alert("Changed to " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="combobox" id="recs" name="recs" onchange="changeRecs">
  <option value=5>5</option>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you would use something like this.

```
$('#recs').on('click', function(){
    //action here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there. You missed the `()` in the change attribute:

```js
function changeRecs() {
  alert('has changed');
}
```

```html
<select class="combobox" id="recs" name="recs" onchange="changeRecs()">
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
    <option value=20>20</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

on change of selection below function vl trigger in jquery. You can use this

```
 $("#recs").change(function() { 
    //perform the operation whatever u required 
 });
```